# ppa for GHC 7.6

Tags: 12.04, ppa, haskell

I was wondering if there is some decently trusted PPA of GHC 7.6? Preferably the newest.

I want a decently recent Haskell platform without having to build from source. I am not experienced enough with Linux to want to bother with my own installations of important software, which would probably be unstructured and ad-hoc. Isn't that what package managers are for, after all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is PPA with different GHC versions. They are intended to be installed side by side with default Ubuntu's ghc package:

https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ghc